# Change of length of curve when Fenchel-Nielsen length coordinate increase

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, teichmuller-theory

Let $F$ be a hyperbolic surface of finite type. Suppose $\alpha$ is a simple closed geodesic and $\beta$ is any closed geodesic intersecting $\alpha$. Consider a Fenchel-Nielsen coordinate of the Teichmuller space containing $\alpha.$ Let $l_{x}$ denote the length of a geodesic $x$.

By "Margulis Lemma", there exists $\epsilon$ such that after $l_{\alpha}<\epsilon$, if we decrease $l_{\alpha}$, $l_{\beta}$ will increase exponentially.

**Q) What happens to $l_{\beta}, $if we start increasing the length of $l_{\alpha}$?**

More precisely, when we just increase $l_{\alpha}$,   given any $L_1$ does there exists $L_2$ such that  $l_{\beta}<L_2$, whenever $l_{\alpha}>L_1$. If so, can we explicitely find a relation between $L_1$ and $L_2$, i.e. what happens to $l_{\beta}$ in a continuous path in the Teichmüller space along which $l_{\alpha}$ increases.

Comment: This seems unlikely to hold as stated. For example if you take a third simple curve which intersects $\beta$ but not $\alpha$ and do Dehn twists around it then you get a sequence of pairwise isometric hyperbolic metrics in Teichmüller space where $l_\alpha$ is (any) constant and $l_\beta$ goes to infinity.

Comment: My question was, what happens if we increase the length of "$\alpha$", not the other way around.

Comment: yes, and if what I said above holds then for any value of $l_\alpha$ there are points in Teichmüller space where $l_\beta$ is as large as you want it to be, in particular there cannot be an upper bound on $l_\beta$ depending only on $l_\alpha$.

Comment: @JeanRaimbault Now I understand your point. I have changed the question a little bit.  I want the relation when $l_{\alpha}$ increases. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The problem remains, because when you increase $l_\alpha$ you can always choose a faraway point in the mapping class group orbit of your hyperbolic structure where $l_\beta$ will be as large as you want. To exclude this you would have to ask something about the minimum of $\ell_\beta$ in (part of) the MCG orbit, I think.

Comment: Another possibility, I guess closer to what you want, would be to look at what happens in a continuous path in Teichmüller space along which $l_\alpha$ increases.

Comment: @JeanRaimbault 0 "I guess closer to what you want, would be to look at what happens in a continuous path in Teichmüller space along which lαlα increases", This is exactly what I want.

Comment: I have the feeling that the behavior of $l_\beta$ depends on the path you're looking at in Teichmüller space, even if you're only considering those along which $l_\alpha$ increases. There is a [paper](http://homeweb.unifr.ch/parlierh/pub/completemarkGT.pdf) by Greg McShane and Hugo Parlier in which they show (section 8), that the sets where $l_\alpha > l_\beta$ and $l_\alpha < l_\beta$ are open and connected, and that their boundary (i.e the set where $l_\alpha = l_\beta$) is connected as well, so you have plenty of paths you can look at with different behavior of $l_\beta$.

Comment: @user331406 Actually I was reading this paper when I asked this question. I also guess that their will be no uniform behavior, it will depend on paths.